# How can I solve the error: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'File'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make my variable of type File have the parameter undefined but I get the error: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'File'.

```
export class CreateProductoComponent implements OnInit {


  public producto:any = {};


  public file: File = undefined;
  
  
  constructor() { 

  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
```

And when I want to use the variable in the method, I get an error saying that it cannot be undefined.

```
//Mètode obtenir imatge directe del input
  fileChangeEvent(event:any):void{
    //Validem imatge
    var file;

    if(event.target.files && event.target.files[0]){ //Validem si rebem imatge desde el input
      file = <File>event.target.files[0]; //Guardem l'arxiu en la variable file
      console.log(file);
    }else{  //Si no hi ha imatge
      iziToast.warning({
        title: 'ERROR',
        class: 'text-danger',
        color: 'red',
        position: 'topRight',
        message: 'No hay imágen'
      });
    }

    

    //Validem la mida de la imatge
    if(file.size <= 4000000){
      if(file.type ==){

      }
    }else{
      iziToast.warning({
        title: 'ERROR',
        class: 'text-danger',
        color: 'red',
        position: 'topRight',
        message: 'La imágen supera los 4MB'
      });
    }

  }
```

Comment: `public file: File = undefined;` - how does this make sense? Presumably your `File` type doesn't include `undefined`. I'm not too familiar with using JS classes with TS, but presumably you could include a `?` to say this property is optional? `public file?: File = undefined;`?

Comment: Don't assign `undefined` to your `file` object unless it is supposed to support that type, in which case you could make it optional or use a type union `public file: File | undefined`. The error should go away if you simply remove the `= undefined` part from that code. Just make sure you initialize the variable to a valid value of type File in the constructor.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: "Not working" means what? Is there a new error? Is it the same error? As it is, your code is not a [mre] and the `if(file.size <= 4000000){` portion is irrelevant to the error you have. As it is, the only thing that is reproducible is the `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'File'` error which we have told you how to resolve.

Comment: I have added new code.

Comment: You are mixing JS and TS, which is part of your issue. For one, avoid using the `any` type at all cost. It defeats the point of TS and results in hard to diagnose errors such as this. For your method, don't do this: `event:any`. `event` should have a well defined type. Look at whatever element triggers the `fileChangeEvent` and determine the event type. Then you can simply use that type. You may be able to use `event: Event`. That said, I don't think your error is actually related to `fileChangeEvent` at all. That method can have runtime errors because the use of `any`, but not TS errors.

Comment: Your issue is related to `var file`. This causes `file` to be undefined. `var` should never be used in TypeScript. You should instead say `let file : File;` Then you are actually using the `File` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your `fileChangeEvent` function. There are multiple issues there, but the main one is the use of `var file` tells TypeScript to use `any` for the type of `file`. This is an antipattern for TypeScript.

The error specifically occurs when you reference `file.size`, because it's possible for `file` to undefined (it's technically possible for `file` to be *any type*).

The following will resolve the error you are facing related to `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'File'`:

Note that the important change here is to first check if `file` exists in your `if (file) ...` condition.

```
//Mètode obtenir imatge directe del input
  fileChangeEvent(event:Event):void{
    //Validem imatge
    let file : File | undefined;

    if(event.target.files && event.target.files[0]){ //Validem si rebem imatge desde el input
      file = <File>event.target.files[0]; //Guardem l'arxiu en la variable file
      console.log(file);
    }else{  //Si no hi ha imatge
      iziToast.warning({
        title: 'ERROR',
        class: 'text-danger',
        color: 'red',
        position: 'topRight',
        message: 'No hay imágen'
      });
    }

    

    //Validem la mida de la imatge
    if(file && file.size <= 4000000){
      // TODO: Complete this code
      // if(file.type ==){
      //
      // }
    }else{
      iziToast.warning({
        title: 'ERROR',
        class: 'text-danger',
        color: 'red',
        position: 'topRight',
        message: 'La imágen supera los 4MB'
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the attribute optional with a question mark, which lets it be undefined too. You may keep it simpler by not assigning `undefined` to the variable, if uninitialized it will be undefined already.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties

```js
export class CreateProductoComponent implements OnInit {


  public producto:any = {};


  public file?: File;
  
  
  constructor() { 

  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
```

Comment: Ok this way, I have no error in the variable, but in the method I do. I have added the code of the method and where I get the error is in the:if(file.size <= 4000000){
      if(file.type ==){

Comment: @JoGaPaPo your samples have nothing to do with each other, because the second code creates an untyped variable named `file`. The problem with `file.size` most likely is simply because `file` is undefined. You need to inform the error and more stuff for us to be able to help you.